# $\min f_λ(x) := 1/2 ||x − z||_2^2 + λ||x||_1 , x ∈ R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Let a vector $z ∈ R^n$ be given. For $λ > 0$ consider the problem

$\min f_λ(x) := 1/2 ||x − z||_2^2 + λ||x||_1 , x ∈ R^n$

(i) Show that for any $λ \geq 0$ this problem has a unique solution $x_λ$.

(ii) Determine the unique solution $x_λ$ (as a function of $λ$ and $z$)

Is it enough to argue for (i) the positivity of norms?
For (ii) i think I have to argue with the subdifferential for $||x||_1$ but am not sure how to do that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed $\lambda\geq 0$, $f_\lambda$ is coercive, i.e.
$$
\lim_{\|x\|_2 \to +\infty} f_\lambda(x) = +\infty,
$$
and strictly convex, being the sum of a strictly convex function ($\|x-z\|_2^2 / 2$) and a convex function ($\lambda \|x\|_1$).
Hence $f_\lambda$ admits a unique minimum point $x_\lambda$, which is characterized by the inclusion $0\in \partial f_\lambda(x_\lambda)$.

If $\lambda = 0$ the unique solution is clearly $x = z$.

Let us consider the case $\lambda > 0$ and let us call $y = x_\lambda$
(to drop the subscript).

Since the subgradient of the function $\varphi(x) = \|x\|_1$ is 
$$
\partial \varphi (x) = \text{sign}(x_1) \times \cdots \times \text{sign}(x_n),
\quad\text{with}\quad
\text{sign}(t) :=
\begin{cases}
[-1,1], &\text{if}\ t = 0,\\
\{t/|t|\}, &\text{if}\ t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},
\end{cases}
$$
the condition $0\in\partial f_\lambda(y)$ on $y$ reads:
$$
0\in \frac{y-z}{\lambda} + \text{sign}(y_1) \times \cdots \times \text{sign}(y_n),
$$
that is
$$
0 \in \frac{y_i - z_i}{\lambda} + \text{sign}(y_i),
\qquad \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}.
$$
This relation entails
$$
y_i =
\begin{cases}
z_i - \lambda, &\text{if}\ z_i > \lambda,\\
z_i + \lambda, &\text{if}\ z_i < -\lambda,\\
0, & \text{if}\ |z_i|\leq \lambda.
\end{cases}
$$